# ExpressionEngine article view only shows latest article

Tags: module, expressionengine, channel

I have a blog that lists articles, when clicking on the link to show the full article it returns the same article, which happens to be the latest. I have made sure that all 3 articles are open. Here is my article template entries tag:

`{exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="1" dynamic="no" disable="categories|member_data|pagination" }`

I have tried it with dynamic on as well, but that doesn't work either. Just in case you think that I happen to be linking to the same article, here is my listing template:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" dynamic="off" status="Open|Featured"}

<div class="entry">
  <p class="title"><a href="{path='news/{title}'}">{title}</a></h2>
  <p class="date meta">{entry_date format="%M %j, %Y"}</p>
  <div class="entry-content">
     {news_summary}
  </div>
</div>  

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the full articles to be at `/news/the-title-of-the-post`

For the full article template, you don't want `dynamic="no"`. Leave it off or explicitly set `dynamic="yes"`.

In your listing template, for your `href` try [`{url_title_path}`](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#url-title-path), which appends the URL title to a template/group of your choice:

```
<p class="title"><a href="{url_title_path='news'}">{title}</a></h2>
```

What's happening is you're loading `/news/The%20Title%20of%20The%20Post`, which is *not* going to match the URL Title. Then, because EE can't find any matching URL title **and** you have `dynamic="no"`, it displays the latest article regardless of the URL.

Comment: Alternatively, you could also use {url_title_path="templategroup/template"} to link from the list page to the detail page

Comment: Good point! `url_title_path` is probably a better choice. I'll update my answer.